# What is the labor time to replace a automatic transmission in a 1991 Ford L8000

Tags: ford, transmission, book-hours

What is the labor time to replace an automatic transmission in a 1991 Ford L8000

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The actual time to do this will vary with the skill and experience of those doing the work.

Comment: @SolarMike - The OP is asking for Book Hours, which are given regardless of the skill of the mechanic. There are industry standards which cover this, just not available to the layman.

Comment: Some of them are available to laymen - my owners handbook gives the "standard hours" for most normal servicing jobs. But replacing an auto transmission isn't part of normal servicing, of course. If you go to a main dealer, you will be charged "by the book", not by how long Joe Torquewrench actually spent on the job.

Comment: But if the OP is wanting the hours to plan doing the job themselves then "book hours" is not really relevant for an 17year old car - rusted / seized bolts etc etc